# Target single button of many on hover using JQuery & stop flickering when visible button hovered

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have created a page with multiple images which when hovered over, fade away and a button appears over the top. The button then hides and the image reappears when the cursor is moved away. I wanted to do this using JQuery to improve my skills. I am fairly new to coding, so would really appreciate some direction on the problem.

I have been able to do both of these things, however;

1 - the button appears on all images (there are 6 in total) rather than just the one that is being hovered over.

2 - when I hover over the button, it and the background image begin to flash. If I click the button, the flashing of the button and image continues.

I believe these is due to how I am targeting the button specifically, but I cannot seem to get it right using the ‘this’ way of targeting. Is this correct or am I missing something very important?

Thank you for your help!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".card-img").hover(
    function() {
      $(this).animate({
        opacity: 0.1,
      }, 600);
    },
    function() {
      $(this).animate({
        opacity: 1.0,
      }, 600);
    });

  $(".card-img").hover(
    function() {
      $(".button-projects").css('visibility', 'visible');
    },
    function() {
      $(".button-projects").css('visibility', 'hidden');
    });

})
```

```css
/* button Styling */

.button-main {
  background-color: #000000;
  border-radius: 100000px;
  color: white;
  padding: 8px 24px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 27px;
  border: none;
}

.card {
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  margin-top: 80px;
  border-radius: 0px;
}

.card-img-top {
  border: black solid 4px;
}

.card-img-ctr {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.card-img {
  border-radius: 0em;
  border-top-right-radius: 0em;
  opacity: 1;
}

.card-img-ctr button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.button-projects {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-img-top card-img-ctr">
        <img class="card-img" alt="Mockup images of Magnetic Eyes project website.">
        <button class="button-main button-projects">More info</button>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-img-top card-img-ctr">
        <img src="assets/images/bottle-brew.jpg" class="card-img" alt="Mockup images of Bottle and Brew project.">
        <button class="button-main button-projects">More info</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why not use CSS for the job?

Comment: @connexo because I wanted to practice my JQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.next()` to find the button associated with the hovered element.

```
$(this).next(".button-projects").css('visibility', 'visible');
```

**Demo**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".card-img-ctr").on("mouseenter",function() {
    $(this).find(".card-img").animate({
      opacity: 0.1,
    }, 600);
    $(this).find(".button-projects").css('visibility', 'visible');
  });

  $(".card-img-ctr").on("mouseleave", function() {
    $(this).find(".card-img").animate({
      opacity: 1.0,
    }, 600);
    $(this).find(".button-projects").css('visibility', 'hidden');
  });



})
```

```css
/* button Styling */

.button-main {
  background-color: #000000;
  border-radius: 100000px;
  color: white;
  padding: 8px 24px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 27px;
  border: none;
}

.card {
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  margin-top: 80px;
  border-radius: 0px;
}

.card-img-top {
  border: black solid 4px;
}

.card-img-ctr {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.card-img {
  border-radius: 0em;
  border-top-right-radius: 0em;
  opacity: 1;
}

.card-img-ctr button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.button-projects {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-img-top card-img-ctr">
        <img class="card-img" alt="Mockup images of Magnetic Eyes project website.">
        <button class="button-main button-projects">More info</button>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-img-top card-img-ctr">
        <img src="assets/images/bottle-brew.jpg" class="card-img" alt="Mockup images of Bottle and Brew project.">
        <button class="button-main button-projects">More info</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this, this does indeed make just the required button visible. I still have the issue of the button and background flickering/coming and going when the button itself is hovered. Do you have any ideas why this could be?

Comment: @michellelclement Then you have to use `mouseenter` and `mouseleave`, check my demo

Comment: Unfortunately the button and image still flicker and flash when you hover over the button. This is really screwing with my head :)

Comment: Try look at the demo now and the code, I change the over element.

Comment: Oh my goodness, you've done it! Thank you so much, I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  $(".card-img").hover(
    function() {
      $(this).animate({
        opacity: 0.1,
      }, 600);
    },
    function() {
      $(this).animate({
        opacity: 1.0,
      }, 600);
    });

  $(".card-img").hover(
    function() {
      $(this).siblings(".button-projects").css('visibility', 'visible');
    },
    function() {
      $(this).siblings(".button-projects").css('visibility', 'hidden');
    });

})
```

```css
/* button Styling */

.button-main {
  background-color: #000000;
  border-radius: 100000px;
  color: white;
  padding: 8px 24px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 27px;
  border: none;
}

.card {
  border: none;
  background-color: transparent;
  margin-top: 80px;
  border-radius: 0px;
}

.card-img-top {
  border: black solid 4px;
}

.card-img-ctr {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.card-img {
  border-radius: 0em;
  border-top-right-radius: 0em;
  opacity: 1;
}

.card-img-ctr button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.button-projects {
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-img-top card-img-ctr">
        <img class="card-img" alt="Mockup images of Magnetic Eyes project website." src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/674010/pexels-photo-674010.jpeg" style="width:100%;height:100px;">
        <button class="button-main button-projects">More info</button>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="card">
      <div class="card-img-top card-img-ctr">
        <img class="card-img" alt="Mockup images of Magnetic Eyes project website." src="https://images.pexels.com/photos/674010/pexels-photo-674010.jpeg" style="width:100%;height:100px;">
        <button class="button-main button-projects">More info</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This you so much, this certainly fixes the issue of the multiple buttons changing. I still have the issue of the flickering, and now the image next to the one hovered flickers too. Any ideas?